# How to generate a complex non-binary tree?

Tags: .net, recursion, tree, c#-2.0

I want to create a complex tree, where every subtree can have several branches that go deep. Where can I find info about this?

EDIT:
OK, binary tree also suits my needs. But I can't find random binary tree generator for C#

Comment: treeoverflow.com?  ;)  Try searching for B-Tree  (rather than binary tree)

Comment: not sure why this question was upvoted. It's not a good question

Answer (score 0):

For an implementation and source:
http://daisley-harrison.com/blog/post/NET-Generic-BTree-Library-and-Source-Code.aspx

For concepts and explanation, Wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: That's nice but I don't need it to be sorted. I just want every level to have random number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Word complex in your question might mean that you don't exactly understand, what particular tree you need ) You should read general material about trees first and you'll find the closest type of tree...

Here is wide range of data-structures including dozens of tree-types: [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)

Answer (score 0):

also good explanation, i'm currently study this  and have found this useful
http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/tree.html
but in general,yandex.com will help you